# Как поменять поведение git merge при обнаружении не разрешающихся конфликтов

Tags: git, git-merge

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ сделать так, чтобы git при обнаружении конфликтов при merge, которые он автоматически не смог разрешить, не делал бы файл со стандартными вставками по типу:

```
<<< HEAD 
... 
=== 
... 
>>> branch
```

А вместо этого создавал бы переименованную копию файла с другой ветки, а изначальный файл не трогал. Мне это надо для разрешения конфликтов с помощью стороннего инструмента, который как раз таки требует 2 сравниваемых файла, а те вставки от гита не принимает.

Comment: использовать mergetool? в конфиге просто зададите путь к Вашей  туле и гит будет ее вызывать, передавая ей два файла на сравнение. А Вы уже решите, что с ними делать

Comment: @KoVadim, неа, mergetool - это трёхпанельное сравнение, а у него прога для двухпанельного.

Comment: На самом деле, гораздо удобнее будет использовать нормальную прогу с трёхпанельным сравнением. Например, winmerge. Ещё можно порыть в сторону написания своего merge driver'а для кастомизированного автоматического слияния - ему доступны 3 файла: новый, старый и общий предок.

Comment: да хоть семипанельного. Прописал скрипт, который вызовет чудо утилиту и поехали.

Comment: Ну если через свои скрипты, то можно намутить. Но с двухпанельным основная проблема в том, что у гита целевой файл отличается от двух сравниваемых, а значит придётся заставить скрипт скопировать потом получившийся файл на место целевого.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Если git поддерживает вашу программу

Есть готовый инструмент [mergetool](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool) через который можно запустить программу для слияния.

Выполните `git mergetool --tool-help`, она покажет список поддерживаемых программ. У меня он такой:

araxis, kdiff3, vimdiff, vimdiff2, vimdiff3, bc, bc3, codecompare, deltawalker, diffmerge, diffuse, ecmerge, emerge, examdiff, guiffy, gvimdiff, gvimdiff2, gvimdiff3, meld, opendiff, p4merge, tkdiff, tortoisemerge, winmerge, xxdiff

Если в этом списке ваша программа есть, установите ее как программу по-умолчанию, например `kdiff3`:

```
git config --global merge.tool kdiff3
# если гит не находит программу, пропишите ее путь в окружении $PATH или явно укажите так:
git config --global mergetool.kdiff3.path "/path/to/kdiff3"
```

Затем выполните слияние `git merge (ваша проблемная ветка)` и запустите программу: `git mergetool`

### Оригинал и новый файл по отдельности

Напишем такой баш скрипт, я его сохранил в домашнем каталоге `/home/pusher/bin/diff.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE="$1"
LOCAL="$2"
REMOTE="$3"
MERGED="$4"

cp "$LOCAL" "$MERGED"
cp "$REMOTE" "$MERGED.new"
```

Он будет "возвращать назад" оригинальный файл и копировать новый в `.new`.

Затем, находясь в каталоге с проектом, настройте его:

```
git config merge.tool copynew
git config mergetool.copynew.cmd '/home/pusher/bin/diff.sh $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED'
git config mergetool.keepBackup false
```

Можно использовать опцию `--global`, тогда эти настройки будут глобальными.

- назначен новый инструмент слияния copynew
- прописан путь до него
- файлы `.orig` не будут сохраняться (чтобы не засорять каталог)

После этого:

- сливаем `git merge (ваша проблемная ветка)` - будет сообщено о конфликтах и файлы будут с теми самыми `<<< HEAD ...`
- запускаем mergetool: `echo y | git mergetool -y -t copynew`

На этом все. Файлы с конфликтами будут возвращены в оригинальное состояние, а также создадутся `.new` файлы, которые по вашему замыслу нужно передать вашему стороннему инструменту.

Comment: `echo y | git mergetool -y -t copynew` - в 2 команды делать как-то не очень круто. Можно заставить гит использовать нужную стратегию слияния сразу при мёрже. Впрочем, я не уверен, что там насчёт подходящей стратегии. Ещё можно сделать свой merge driver, который будет вызываться автоматически при мёрдже.

Comment: Хм.. А на основе чего формируется список тулов? У меня вот так: ```git mergetool --tool-help
'git mergetool --tool=<tool>' may be set to one of the following:
 vimdiff
 vimdiff2
 vimdiff3
 winmerge

The following tools are valid, but not currently available:
 araxis
 bc
 bc3
 codecompare
 deltawalker
 diffmerge
 diffuse
 ecmerge
 emerge
 examdiff
 gvimdiff
 gvimdiff2
 gvimdiff3
 kdiff3
 meld
 opendiff
 p4merge
 tkdiff
 tortoisemerge
 xxdiff

Some of the tools listed above only work in a windowed
environment. If run in a terminal-only session, they will fail.```

Comment: @Qwertiy, у git есть переменная среды MERGE_TOOLS_DIR, содержащая путь к папкес со скриптами. Тупо делается `ls` по ней.

Comment: @Qwertiy `в 2 команды делать как-то не очень круто. Можно заставить гит использовать нужную стратегию слияния сразу при мёрже`. Там не про стратегию слияния, а ТС хочет diff самостоятельно делать, и для этого и есть мержтул. При его запуске на каждый сливаемый файлик нужно нажать `y` плюс подтвердить, что все слито верно - еще `y`. В общем, чтобы никаких приглашений не выдавалась, используется такой паровоз. `Ещё можно сделать свой merge driver` - спасибо буду знать. Я про мержтул из первого коммента узнал.

Comment: @TotalPusher, я не про число `y`. Я имел в виду, что одна команда - это `git merge`, а вторая - запуск тула. По идее должно быть можно обойтись только git merge.